# Processor design, signal values

Tags: assembly, mips, processor

[image]

[image]

My solution:

On line 3: 1: 0x1 or 0x0, 2: unknown, 3: unknown, 4: $t1, 5: $t0, 6: $a0, 7: $t0, 0x0

On line 4: 1: unknown, 2: unknown, 3: unknown, 4: $t0, 5: unknown, 6: unknown, 7: unknown, 8: 0x1

Is this even remotely correct? How do I solve this? I feel a bit lost.

Comment: It's better to put the image of text as text. Images can't be searched, aren't friendly to those with visual impairments, and waste space and bandwidth. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding line 3, `slt`:

Path 1: yes, the value will be either 0 or 1.

I don't know what your coursework is expecting, but the values for line 3, `slt`, for paths 2 & 3 are knowable.

For path 2, it is true that an `slt` instruction does not read or write data memory, but that doesn't change that we can still know what WD is then, and, it's going to be the ***value in** the `$a0` register*.

For path 3, this is the sign extended immediate of the `slt` machine code instruction.  Of course, the `slt` instruction in an R-type, not an I-type, but the hardware there doesn't care — it will still sign extend the lower 16-bits of the R-type instruction (interpreting it there as if it were an I-type), only to discard or ignore that work shortly later.  In order to determine the value of that path, we must know the machine code value of the instruction, which happens to be 0x0124402a.  So, the 402a will be sign extended to 32 bits and that is the value on path 3 (which will go unused due to `ALUSrc` selecting the register output instead).

For path 4 you state `$t1`, which is correct, but let's be specific and say the ***value in** the `$t1` register*.

For path 5 you state: `$t0`, 6 — I'm not sure what you mean by that, but this is a 5 bit path that is a register name, so it is going to be the ***name of** the `$t0`
register*, which is 8.

For path 6 you state: `$a0`, 7 — again not sure what you mean by that, but this is also a 5 bit path that is a register name, so it is going to be the ***name of** the `$a0` register*, which is 4.  (And we can also note that due to `RegDst` being true, this path is ignored.)

Lastly, path 7 is also a 5 bit path and it will be the ***name of** the `$t0` register*, which is 8.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It cleared up a few things for me. But for line 4, I don't understand how I should figure out what signal  3 and 7 should be since I don't have the 16-bit immediate, only the label. Could you please help me? @Erik

Comment: You have the distance from the branch to the label.  You will have to compute the 16-bit immediate.  The branch target is only a few instructions away, and is encoded as a pc-relative immediate.  That immediate will basically be the number of instructions jumping forward (biased by 1 or so depending on where you're counting from).

Comment: Ok! So is this correct?: **1:** Unknown, **2:** $0, **3:** 0x00000007, **4:** The value in the $t0 register, **5:** Unknown, **6:** Name of the $0 register, which is 0, **7:** 0x0, **8:** 0x1 @Erik

Comment: Yes: 1 is unknown, b/c minimally, we don't know `MemToReg` for beq (it is a don't care signal since `RegWrite` is false).  Yes, 2 is $0 but that's known to be 0x0.  Yes, I believe 3 is 7.  Yes, 4 is value in `$t0`.  Yes, 5 is indeed unknown b/c we don't know `RegDest`, since it is a don't care for `beq` (but we could determine the two exact possible values).  Yes, 6 is name of $0, which is 0x0.  Yes, 7 is the upper 0's of the small positive immediate (7).  But 8 is unknown, since it depends on the dynamic equality between `$t0` and 0: it will be 0 until the last iteration of the loop, then 1.